# Bootstrap datepicker is coming beyond the footer of the website

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

I am updating a website , where we have a page of form for reservation.
For the date textbox, It is used bootstrap datepicker for the date.
It is a codeigniter project.

When i try to reload the page , i see that **date box** below the footer of the website.
And when i try to scroll up to the page and click on the date textbox , the date box below the footer get disappear.
 
It looks something strange for me

This is my javascript code to have the date.

```
$(".datepicker-1").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImageOnly: true

        }).datepicker("setDate", new Date()).val();
```

This is the code of div that contain date picker

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1;">
<div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-corner-all">
......
......
.....
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me to find a way to **hide** the `<div id="ui-datepicker-div"/>` when page loads initially (i.e "Not to see on below the footer of the website") and display it as usual the process goes on (i.e as usual, it should trigger the date picker ) . Suggest me any javascript code.


For the information the `<div id />` which i showed you before is not shown in the root coding page.

Comment: you have given z-index only to datepicker you have to give it to your footer also

Comment: I tried z-index on footer but it doesn't work. Can you do anything on javascript to hide initially when the page load and get back when to click on that date box.

Comment: you have to give z-index to both footer and datepicker higher value will be seen above and lower value will be seen above...... regarding jquery you to hide element do some research you will find one on google

Comment: I found a different way to solve it.
Anyway thank you for your reply @khizarsyed